# Locking with Tornado and multiple instances

Tags: python, locking, tornado

I'm fairly new to Python and Tornado, so please forgive if I overcomplicated a long-solved problem, but I didn't find much else out there.

I'm running multiple Tornado instances (multiple instances per server, multiple servers) for an application and have some tasks that only one instance should perform, such as scheduling certain events in the application. Instead of running a dedicated instance that performs this task, I'd like to have an opportunistic approach where the first instance that tries gets to do the job.

Part of my solution is a database based locking mechanism (MongoDB `findAndUpdate`). The code below seems to work just fine but I'd like to get some advice if this is a good solution or if there are ready-made locking and task distribution solutions out there for Tornado.

This is the decorator that acquires the lock when entering the function and releases it afterwards:

```
def locking(fn):
    @tornado.gen.engine
    def wrapped(wself, *args, **kwargs):
        @tornado.gen.engine
        def wrapped_callback(*cargs, **ckwargs):
            logging.info("release lock")
            yield tornado.gen.Task(lock.release_lock)
            logging.info("release lock done")
            original_callback(*cargs, **ckwargs)

        logging.info("acquire lock")
        yield tornado.gen.Task(model.SchedulerLock.initialize_lock, area_id=wself.area_id)
        lock = yield tornado.gen.Task(model.SchedulerLock.acquire_lock, area_id=wself.area_id)
        if lock:
            logging.info("acquire lock done")
            original_callback = kwargs['callback']
            kwargs['callback'] = wrapped_callback
            fn(wself, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            logging.info("acquire lock not possible, postponed")
            ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
            ioloop.add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=2), functools.partial(wrapped, wself, *args, **kwargs))

    return wrapped
```

The `acquire_lock` method returns the lock object or `False`

Any thoughts on this? I know that the lock is only half of the solution, as I also need a mechanism that ensures that a one-off task only gets done once. However, this can be achieved very similarly. Is there anything that solves the problem more elegantly?